# Query not returning all records based on just the date from a date-time field

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am storing Date-Time values in a field as part of a POS program. To view the sales from a particular day I need to be able to retrieve all the records based on just the date - excluding the time. I have found some code that I thought worked but I can't get any records returned with single digit days... 12/5/2019 vs 11/26/2019. Here is the code I have. TimeStamp.text contains a date such as 12/4/2019 6:33:00 PM. I am connecting to an access database.

```
Private Sub TimeStamp_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimeStamp.DoubleClick
    Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse(TimeStamp.Text)
    Dim dateString = dt.ToShortDateString()
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = "DateStamp = '" & dateString & "'"
    SalesBindingSource.Sort = "SalesID DESC"
    Infobox.Text = "All records from " & dateString
    GetTax()
    TotalRows()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably due to the date format being utilised. I presume you are expecting to use `mm/dd/yyyy`, whereas the format is probably 'dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: The lines Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse(TimeStamp.Text)
                Dim dateString = dt.ToShortDateString() are returning "11/6/2019" in the dateString variable. This is the same format as my database except for the additional time part. I'm sure it has something to do with formatting since it has no problems retrieving double-digit-day dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is expecting a 2 digit day.

```
    Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse(TimeStamp.Text)
    Dim dateString = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks Mary. I played around with formats for an hour last night and gave up. Such a little change but a huge step forward.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to start converting date values to strings and messing around with the "hope" that the data engine sees some string as a date.

In ACE/JET, there is a built in function that strips out the time part.

eg:

```
Select ID, CustID, DATEVALUE(PurchaseDate) as Pdate from tblInvoices
```

If you going to query on above? Then you use a correctly formated date:

```
SELECT ID, CustID, DATEVALUE(PurchaseDate) AS Pdate from tblInvoices
WHERE Pdate = #12/06/2019#
```

So the Access DATEVALUE() function can be used in your queries. However, do keep in mind that high speed indexing can't be used with above. So, if the tables are large? You  want this:

```
SELECT ID, CustID, PurchaseDate from tblInvoices
WHERE PurchaseDate >= #12/06/2019# AND PurchaseDate < #12/07/2019#
```

So if the tables are not too large, or you have other criteria that limits the data pull with some index, then DATEVALUE() should be used to strip out the time part. However, for a large table, this results in loss of the indexing, and will cause full table scans. Thus sending a whole "range" for the data criteria is preferred.

Comment: Thanks very much Mr Kallal. Getting rid of the time portion of the date is really all I needed. Alhough I have my code working now, I plan on going back and addressing this with your solution. I agree that 'hoping the engine' can figure out the date is a poor practice.